# jqwidgets fails to load data from JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jqwidget

I am trying to load jqwidgets grid from JSON Response. 
Grid Loads with empty data without any error.
Below is Json response and jquery code. Please tell me is i miss something here?

**JSON DATA :**

```
 {"holidayrule":["{\"hid\":\"263\",\"hdates\":\"06/21/2015, 06/22/2015, 06/23/2015, 06/24/2015, 06/25/2015, 06/26/2015, 06/27/2015, 06/28/2015, 06/29/2015, 06/30/2015, 07/01/2015, 07/02/2015\",\"hremark\":\"MyRuleRemark\",\"created_date\":\"2015-02-10 09:59:57.44\",\"updated_date\":\"2015-02-10 09:59:57.44\",\"hname\":\"MyRuleName\"}","{\"hid\":\"264\",\"hdates\":\"05/08/2015, 05/09/2015, 05/10/2015, 05/11/2015, 05/12/2015, 05/13/2015, 05/14/2015, 05/15/2015, 05/16/2015, 05/17/2015, 05/18/2015, 05/19/2015\",\"hremark\":\"ggfgf\",\"created_date\":\"2015-02-10 11:08:52.489\",\"updated_date\":\"2015-02-10 11:08:52.489\",\"hname\":\"gfd\"}","{\"hid\":\"265\",\"hdates\":\"01/23/2015, 01/24/2015, 01/25/2015, 01/26/2015, 01/27/2015, 01/28/2015, 01/29/2015, 01/30/2015, 01/31/2015, 02/01/2015, 02/02/2015, 02/03/2015\",\"hremark\":\"ghhghhghhg\",\"created_date\":\"2015-02-10 15:22:11.69\",\"updated_date\":\"2015-02-10 15:22:11.69\",\"hname\":\"fggg\"}","{\"hid\":\"266\",\"hdates\":\"02/25/2015, 02/26/2015, 02/27/2015, 02/28/2015, 03/01/2015, 03/02/2015, 03/03/2015, 03/04/2015, 03/05/2015, 03/06/2015, 03/07/2015, 03/08/2015\",\"hremark\":\"df\",\"created_date\":\"2015-02-10 15:22:26.133\",\"updated_date\":\"2015-02-10 15:22:26.133\",\"hname\":\"gfggf\"}","{\"hid\":\"267\",\"hdates\":\"01/07/2015, 01/08/2015, 01/09/2015, 01/10/2015, 01/11/2015, 01/12/2015, 01/13/2015, 01/14/2015, 01/15/2015, 01/16/2015, 01/17/2015, 01/18/2015\",\"hremark\":\"hghhghgh\",\"created_date\":\"2015-02-10 15:41:22.527\",\"updated_date\":\"2015-02-10 15:41:22.527\",\"hname\":\"33232\"}","{\"hid\":\"268\",\"hdates\":\"01/15/2015, 01/16/2015, 01/17/2015, 01/18/2015, 01/19/2015, 01/20/2015, 01/21/2015, 01/22/2015, 01/23/2015, 01/24/2015, 01/25/2015, 01/26/2015\",\"hremark\":\"dfdfdfdfd\",\"created_date\":\"2015-02-10 16:23:37.855\",\"updated_date\":\"2015-02-10 16:23:37.855\",\"hname\":\"sdffddf\"}"]}
```

**JQUERY :**

```
var parsedData = JSON.stringify(data.holidayrule);
var source =
        {
            localdata: parsedData,
            datatype: "json"
        }
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
// initialize divHolidayruleData
$("#divHolidayruleData").jqxGrid(
{
    width: 850,
    source: dataAdapter,
    pageable: true,
    autoheight: true,
    sortable: true,
    altrows: true,
    columns: [
      { text: 'HID', datafield: 'hid', align: 'center', cellsalign: 'center', width: 70 },
      { text: 'Rule Name', datafield: 'hname', cellsalign: 'center', align: 'center', width: 200 },
      { text: 'Holiday Dates', datafield: 'hdates', align: 'center', cellsalign: 'center', width: 200 },
      { text: 'Remark', datafield: 'hremark', align: 'center', cellsalign: 'center', width: 150 },
      { text: 'Created Date', datafield: 'created_date', align: 'center', cellsalign: 'center', width: 100 },
      { text: 'Updated Date', datafield: 'updated_date', align: 'center', cellsalign: 'center', width: 130 }
    ]
});
```

Am i missing something here?

**EDIT :**

```
 ["{\"hid\":263,\"hdates\":\"06/21/2015, 06/22/2015, 06/23/2015, 06/24/2015, 06/25/2015, 06/26/2015, 06/27/2015, 06/28/2015, 06/29/2015, 06/30/2015, 07/01/2015, 07/02/2015\",\"hremark\":\"MyRuleRemark\",\"created_date\":\"2015-02-10 09:59:57.44\",\"updated_date\":\"2015-02-10 09:59:57.44\",\"hname\":\"MyRuleName\"}","{\"hid\":264,\"hdates\":\"05/08/2015, 05/09/2015, 05/10/2015, 05/11/2015, 05/12/2015, 05/13/2015, 05/14/2015, 05/15/2015, 05/16/2015, 05/17/2015, 05/18/2015, 05/19/2015\",\"hremark\":\"ggfgf\",\"created_date\":\"2015-02-10 11:08:52.489\",\"updated_date\":\"2015-02-10 11:08:52.489\",\"hname\":\"gfd\"}","{\"hid\":265,\"hdates\":\"01/23/2015, 01/24/2015, 01/25/2015, 01/26/2015, 01/27/2015, 01/28/2015, 01/29/2015, 01/30/2015, 01/31/2015, 02/01/2015, 02/02/2015, 02/03/2015\",\"hremark\":\"ghhghhghhg\",\"created_date\":\"2015-02-10 15:22:11.69\",\"updated_date\":\"2015-02-10 15:22:11.69\",\"hname\":\"fggg\"}","{\"hid\":266,\"hdates\":\"02/25/2015, 02/26/2015, 02/27/2015, 02/28/2015, 03/01/2015, 03/02/2015, 03/03/2015, 03/04/2015, 03/05/2015, 03/06/2015, 03/07/2015, 03/08/2015\",\"hremark\":\"df\",\"created_date\":\"2015-02-10 15:22:26.133\",\"updated_date\":\"2015-02-10 15:22:26.133\",\"hname\":\"gfggf\"}","{\"hid\":267,\"hdates\":\"01/07/2015, 01/08/2015, 01/09/2015, 01/10/2015, 01/11/2015, 01/12/2015, 01/13/2015, 01/14/2015, 01/15/2015, 01/16/2015, 01/17/2015, 01/18/2015\",\"hremark\":\"hghhghgh\",\"created_date\":\"2015-02-10 15:41:22.527\",\"updated_date\":\"2015-02-10 15:41:22.527\",\"hname\":\"33232\"}","{\"hid\":268,\"hdates\":\"01/15/2015, 01/16/2015, 01/17/2015, 01/18/2015, 01/19/2015, 01/20/2015, 01/21/2015, 01/22/2015, 01/23/2015, 01/24/2015, 01/25/2015, 01/26/2015\",\"hremark\":\"dfdfdfdfd\",\"created_date\":\"2015-02-10 16:23:37.855\",\"updated_date\":\"2015-02-10 16:23:37.855\",\"hname\":\"sdffddf\"}"]
```

Same problem with above JSON

**EDIT 2:**

**[jsFiddleDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/usuznxku/13/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed one of the most basic concepts in the Data Binding through Data Apdater - datafields array is undefined in your code. Each datafield should have "name" and "type". Your data is also within "holidayrule" which means that you'll have to set the source object's "root" property, too.

Updated:

```
  var data = "[" +
```

"{\"hid\":263,\"hdates\":\"06/21/2015, 06/22/2015, 06/23/2015, 06/24/2015, 06/25/2015, 06/26/2015, 06/27/2015, 06/28/2015, 06/29/2015, 06/30/2015, 07/01/2015, 07/02/2015\",\"hremark\":\"MyRuleRemark\",\"created_date\":\"2015-02-10 09:59:57.44\",\"updated_date\":\"2015-02-10 09:59:57.44\",\"hname\":\"MyRuleName\"}"
        + "]";
        var source = {
            localdata: data,
            datafields: [{ name: 'hname', type: 'string' }],
            datatype: "json"
        };

```
    var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

    $("#jqxgridTest").jqxGrid({
        width: 670,
        source: dataAdapter,
        altrows: true,
        selectionmode: 'multiplecellsextended',
        columns: [{
            text: 'HID',
            datafield: 'hid',
            width: 70
        }, {
            text: 'Rule Name',
            datafield: 'hname',
            width: 70
        }, {
            text: 'Holiday Dates',
            datafield: 'hdates',
            width: 70
        }, {
            text: 'Remark',
            datafield: 'hremark',
            width: 70
        }, {
            text: 'Created Date',
            datafield: 'created_date',
            width: 70
        }, {
            text: 'Updated Date',
            datafield: 'updated_date',
            width: 70
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: I have added jsFiddle demo. facing Same Problem